# Restrict date past 60 days

Tags: date, datepicker, drupal-8

I was working in Drupal 8 custom forms. I like to restrict or block user  purchase date not more than 60 days
I tried with three methods. it wont work. Please help for me
I tried with jquery but style are afftected and format are also changed.

```
$form['product_info']['install_date'] = [
      '#type' => 'date',
      '#title' => $this->t('Date of Install *'),
      '#default_value' => $this->store->get('install_date') ? $this->store->get(
            'install_date') : "",
      '#date_format' => "m/d/Y",
      '#size' => 10,
//First method
     '#minDate'=> '-60',
 //second Method
     '#datepicker_options' => array('minDate' => 0,),
//Third Method    
'     #attributes' => ('min' =>  \Drupal::service('date.formatter')->format(REQUEST_TIME, '-60', 'Y-m-d'),
    ),
            // '#required' => TRUE,.
      '#prefix' => '<div class="field-wrapper">',
      '#suffix' => '</div>',
      '#error_no_message' => TRUE,
    ];
```

Comment: What about using the form validation to restrict the date with a message explaining the issue ?

Comment: hi Kevin
Thanks for your Comments.
user will not select date more than 60 days